# How can I backfill null rows in one column with the limit based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains daily data for multiple customers, there are many rows of data that have values for the cust_id and read_dt but the readPeriod and daily_cons are both null. I want to backfill the null rows in the daily_cons column when the readPeriod > 1 which indicates that the daily_cons is meant for the current row and the previous X rows based on the readPeriod value. So if the readPeriod is 4 then the last 3 rows should be filled with the current row's daily_cons value.

I need to do it this way specifically because this dataset contains daily data that is very messy. The daily_cons column is calculated based on start and end reads on a register and should be distributed over all the days in that readPeriod. Each read should be ~1 day but many times the network does not communicate properly so there will be start and end reads going over multiple days. Sometimes there are days just completely missing where they are not covered in between the start and end reads. I only want to backfill the known values which would be the rows with readPeriods > 1.

Right now my data follows the pattern below:

```
starting dataframe = {
    'cust_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1 2, 2, 2,2,2,2],
    'read_dt': ['2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', '2023-08-03', '2023-08-04', '2023-08-05', '2023-08-06', '2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', '2023-08-03', '2023-08-04', '2023-08-05', '2023-08-06'],
    'readPeriod': [1, None, None, 3, None, 1, 1, 1, None, None, None, 4],
    'daily_cons': [10, None, None, 15, None, 24, 13, 16, None, None, None, 14]
}
```

I would like to backfill so that my results look like this:

```
resulting dataframe after backfilling = {
    'cust_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1 2, 2, 2,2,2,2],
    'read_dt': ['2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', '2023-08-03', '2023-08-04', '2023-08-05', '2023-08-06', '2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', '2023-08-03', '2023-08-04', '2023-08-05', '2023-08-06'],
    'readPeriod': [1, None, None, 3, None, 1, 1, 1, None, None, None, 4],
    'daily_cons': [10, 15, 15, 15, None, 24, 13, 16, 14, 14, 14, 14]
}
```

I have tried so many different ways to solve this problem. Including using conditions, apply, transform. Here is what I was last trying:

```
condition = (dc['readPeriod'] > 1)
dc['daily_cons'] = dc.groupby('cust_id')['daily_cons'].apply(lambda x: x.bfill() if condition.any() else x)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck endlessly trying to figure this out. Even if it means taking a new approach from my original dataset (the example is after I've created a skeleton df with all the possible dates for each customer and merged the daily data on the end read date, daily_cons is calculated by taking (end_read-begin_read)/readPeriod).

Using this code I get the following results:

```
m1 = dc['readPeriod'].notna()

m2 = (dc.loc[::-1, 'readPeriod'].fillna(-1)
        .groupby(dc['id']).cumsum()
        .ge(1)
     )

dc['daily_cons'] = dc['daily_cons'].bfill().where(m1|m2)
```

| cust_id | read_dt | readPeriod | daily_cons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-01-19 | 1.0 | 20.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-20 | 1.0 | 20.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-21 | 1.0 | 40.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-22 | 1.0 | 0.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-23 | NaN | 26.666667 |
| 4 | 2023-01-24 | NaN | 26.666667 |
| 4 | 2023-01-25 | 3.0 | 26.666667 |
| 4 | 2023-01-26 | 1.0 | 20.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-27 | 1.0 | 10.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-28 | 1.0 | 50.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-29 | 1.0 | 30.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-30 | 1.0 | 10.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-01-31 | 1.0 | 120.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-01 | 1.0 | 110.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-02 | 1.0 | 70.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-03 | 1.0 | 100.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-04 | 1.0 | 80.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-05 | 1.0 | 30.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-06 | 1.0 | 90.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-07 | 1.0 | 80.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-08 | 1.0 | 40.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-09 | NaN | 40.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-10 | NaN | 40.000000 |
| 4 | 2023-02-11 | 1.0 | 40.000000 |

read_dt 2023-02-09 and 2023-02-10 are both backfilled when they should remain NaN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reversed [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with [`fillna(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to identify the previous days with a limit:

```
m1 = df['readPeriod'].notna()

m2 = (df.loc[::-1, 'readPeriod'].fillna(-1)
        .groupby(df['cust_id']).cumsum()
        .ge(1)
     )

df['daily_cons'] = df['daily_cons'].bfill().where(m1|m2)
```

If the days are not necessarily successive, `fillna` with the real day difference:

```
m1 = df['readPeriod'].notna()

days = df.groupby('cust_id')['read_dt'].diff(-1).dt.days

m2 = (df.loc[::-1, 'readPeriod']
        .fillna(days)
        .groupby(df['cust_id']).cumsum()
        .ge(1)
     )

df['daily_cons'] = df['daily_cons'].bfill().where(m1|m2)
```

Output:

```
    cust_id     read_dt  readPeriod  daily_cons
0         1  2023-08-01         1.0        10.0
1         1  2023-08-02         NaN        15.0
2         1  2023-08-03         NaN        15.0
3         1  2023-08-04         3.0        15.0
4         1  2023-08-05         NaN         NaN
5         1  2023-08-06         1.0        24.0
6         2  2023-08-01         1.0        13.0
7         2  2023-08-02         1.0        16.0
8         2  2023-08-03         NaN        14.0
9         2  2023-08-04         NaN        14.0
10        2  2023-08-05         NaN        14.0
11        2  2023-08-06         4.0        14.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I tried both methods but it still fills the nulls when the leakPeriod = 1 so this solution does not work for me.

Comment: @learningthelongway can you provide an updated example (input+output)?

Comment: I edited the original post with a sample result df showing where there is correct and incorrect backfilling, thanks.